# Import character in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Is there a way to do any one of these (on PC version):

- Start a new game with an old character keeping perks and level
- Reset the main quest line back to the escape from Helgen
- Reset entire world except character

Comment: There is definitely a command to reset all quests but I have no memory of what that is.

Comment: There is no "Newgame+" option in Skyrim. What exactly were you hoping to keep? It might be easier to do it the otherway - start a new character and use the console to immediately get what you got in the last game.

Comment: Also, is it possible to import a character to another computer?

Comment: @Avien yes, that's easy enough.  See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/transferring-skyrim-saved-games-from-one-machine-to-another

Answer (score 1):

Answer to No. 1 - No, I don't think it's possible, I've tried many times but never got it to actually work...sorry

Answer to No. 2 - You're going to have to start a new game to do that... there's no other way.

Answer to No. 3 - No.