# Can I backup and restore my Skyrim saves if I plan on installing a new OS?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring Skyrim saved games from one machine to another](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/transferring-skyrim-saved-games-from-one-machine-to-another)

I am going to upgrade my machine from Windows XP to Windows 7, and I want to keep my Skyrim saves.  Is there a safe, working way to do this?

Comment: You might also want to read: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/where-are-the-save-file-in-skyrim

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to just copy you save to an external drive, and put them back after having reinstalled the game. The savegames are located in `C:\Documents and Settings\<Username>\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves` by default.

Also, they may be synchronized by the Steam Cloud. In this case, they'll automatically be restored after you install the game.

Your best bet would be to save your savegames, reinstall the system, Steam and Skyrim, and try to see if they are there. If not, you can restore them manually

Comment: ok jupotter thank you!if smt happens i will ask again!