# How do I enter cheat codes on Xbox 360?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, cheats

I'm trying to enter a cheat code for finding something in *Skyrim*, but I don't know how to enter the cheat codes on the Xbox 360. Where and how do I do it?

Answer (score 17):

You can't, console commands (or "cheat codes", as you put it), are exclusive to the PC version.

You can, however, move your save to PC and input the desired commands there, then transfer it back to your console. [Transferring Skyrim saved games from one machine to another](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/transferring-skyrim-saved-games-from-one-machine-to-another)

Comment: If you consider the question answered, you should click the grey checkmark next to the best answer. When the checkmark turns green, the question is considered answered.

Answer (score 1):

To use certain [console commands](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) (AKA "cheat codes") on the Xbox 360, you need a mod called [**Multi-Utility** 6.1 by Selyb](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206002222/https://www.xboxchaos.com/topic/2839-multi-utility-mod-by-selyb/), which requires a JTAG-RGH modded Xbox 360.

[image: Screenshot of Multi-Utility 6.1 menu]

> Multi-Utility is a Skyrim mod that adds a menu with many console functions for Xbox 360 and PS3 users.

> Usage: Equip Multi-Utility from Powers in the Magic menu.

Before using the mod, read the [UESP wiki article on console commands](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) and the [mod description and usage instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206002222/https://www.xboxchaos.com/topic/2839-multi-utility-mod-by-selyb/) carefully, as the supported console commands and the instructions for running them may differ from those on the PC.

Xbox One and Xbox Series X/S players can use the [Xbox One port of Multi-Utility](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/4067343).