# Transferring Skyrim's saved game files to a new computer

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring Skyrim saved games from one machine to another](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/transferring-skyrim-saved-games-from-one-machine-to-another)

I have recently bought a new laptop. I would like to continue playing Skyrim with the old save files. Copying these files into the save folder does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume you've put them in the right folder? Best to make a save in the game first to let it create the folder. Also, longshot, is the date and time set correctly on your computer? Otherwise the timestamps go all wonky!

Comment: If you were on XP previously and are now on Windows 7, it might be expecting them to be elsewhere.

Comment: Please add more information about your systems, game versions, etc. It's possible that an updated/patched installer game doesn't work with old saved files.

Answer (score 4):

In **Windows 7** the Skyrim saves exist under the following folder.

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves
```

Under **Windows XP** the saves should be in the following folder.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\My Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves
```

If your save games were created in an older version of the game than you are trying to load them in, then they should appear just fine. Make sure the game is fully updated.

Incidentally, Windows 7 creates junction points for the old Windows XP folder structure, so even if you tried to copy the folders exactly from an XP machine, ideally Windows will still know where to find them.

I have copied saves just by using this folder location without issue.

Comment: Windows 8 is `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves` (tested on 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to jump into the game, create a new character and then make a quick-save.  This way you can determine the location it expects the files.  Skyrim normally uses your My Documents / My Games folder for its saves, but they might end up somewhere wierd on win7 cause of the new 'Saved Games' repository.  I normally override this to point at my documents for the sake of avoiding confusion with some games.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Gamesave.info](http://gamesave.info/#ElderScrolls5Skyrim), You can find the save location for Skyrim here:

`<userdocuments>\My Games\Skyrim`, and
`<localappdata>\Skyrim`

Comment: Please add the location into your answer.