# Disc error when loading saves transferred from PC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I learned that you could [transfer a PC Skyrim save to Xbox 360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/transferring-skyrim-saved-games-from-one-machine-to-another) by simply changing the `.ess` extension to `.dat` then put the dat file inside the game shell using Modio.

When I do that and try to load the transferred save the 360 says the disc needs to be cleaned. This only happens when I try to load the modded saves – if I create a new game all is fine.

When I change the extension I simply *rename* `filename.ess` to `filename.dat` via right-clicking – am I doing something wrong? the only issue i can immediately see... is the characters names were different

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transferring Skyrim saved games from one machine to another](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35003/transferring-skyrim-saved-games-from-one-machine-to-another)

Comment: @kotekzot The problem here is an inexplicable disc read error after following transfer instructions. That is not going to be addressed by the other question. New problem, new question... just like we tell people who post follow-up problems as answers to do, right?

Comment: Did you have ANY steam mods from the PC version? This could be your problem. Steam mods are not in xbox and thus reference a different area of code that either A) Doesn't exist on the 360 OR B) References a value that was specific to PC, OR do you have all the same DLC? Referencing some DLC in one save will be Detrimental to having it be played on the console. PC's should be able to read the save and update as necessary. OH WAIT! Almost forgot, Are the game versions the same? If not then yet again, we are at the references to code that doesn't exist. All very tricky.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie considering console players have no ability to diagnose or fix software issues, I thought the best we could do is provide the correct way to transfer saves.

Comment: @kotekzot That's not what duplication is for. If that is the *answer*, it is posted as an answer with a link to the correct instructions, and then voted on. After all, you may be wrong about what's wrong (q.v. Cole's comment). Close votes as duplicate are not for "I know the answer and it's over here", since that makes them super-votes for your answer-that-you-didn't-post.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie if we're going to argue technicalities, then I'm going to point out that this question is essentially asking "how do I transfer a PC save to 360 without errors", and considering that "without errors" is redundant it is pretty much an exact duplicate.

Comment: @kotekzot That's not a valid "technicality". We are here to solve problems. This is not the same problem. Not a duplicate. That's not a "technicality" in the pejorative sense, that's a technicality in the *what this site is for* sense. If you have an answer, and the answer is "just do it right the first time", then post it. Don't use close votes invalidly. You may be right, and you may be wrong. I strongly suspect that this problem can't be *only* caused by following the instructions wrong, since Cole's suspicions are highly likely. If there are multiple possibilities, voting is in order.

Comment: @ColeBusby well no... the pc save had no dlc the xbox version does and i didnt purchase it from steam on the pc so i dont think there would have been any steam mods that being said if im moving it from the pc to the xbox shouldnt it be able to update itself as it would have on the pc?

Comment: @user61369 Not exactly, Ideally you would want the dlc to match, I've only done an xbox to xbox transfer using modio. PC patches are released much faster and in a much different fashion than xbox patches are. If your PC version is a few steps above the Xbox then we're looking at the points I made earlier. Have you tried taking a base save from the xbox to the PC? See if they match when you do that. It could be that the DLC needs to be the same between systems. OR Are you using a patched/cracked/pirated copy (Dont answer that)? If you are, it may be because of the patch info in the save.

Comment: well damn guess i'll have to play legit and i was looking forward to the endless gold...ah well thanks cole