# How can I get a follower if it's bugged?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing on PS4. I've gone to multiple pages and done everything that has been said. (i.e. waiting days, going to jail, doing quests that remove or replace the follower) But the thing is, I only use two followers, Serena and Marcurio, and I know where both of them are, but neither are my current follower and they both tell me I have someone with me so they can't become my follower. Please help.

Comment: Do either of these links help? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44581, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38558

Comment: I tested all the things on each of those links that I could already, except for restarting the game, in which I just did and it did not work sadly.

Comment: Guess I'm out of ideas then. :-/ Unless you can transfer your saved game to a PC and edit it in a Windows copy of Skyrim.

Comment: I could try this, how would I do so?

Comment: I can’t find anything on how to do it for a PS4, but this has instructions for a PS3: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35003. I’ve never tried it before, but some people have apparently gotten it to work.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to give it a try, I appreciate it.

Comment: It might help to know what quest you were doing (or had recently done), as some are more suspect than others (e.g. I think I had problems with one of the Companions' ones).